# Howto transfer BTC/ETH from coinbase to Mist / ethereum wallet

Tags: ether, bitcoin, ethereum-wallet-dapp, shapeshift

recently I bought some BTC on CoinBase. I've transfered the whole amount from the CoinBase BTC wallet into the CoinBase ethereum wallet. But how can I send that ETH into my Mist/Ethereum Wallet (e.g. using my wallet contract as receipient) ?

kind regards
Dominik

Comment: see my answer for the final solution.

Comment: How do I buy EOS from my ethereum wallet on coinbase?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you're not sending it to your Mist wallet.  You're sending it to another Ethereum address.  Mist just helps you create accounts/addresses that are recognized by the Ethereum node that's embedded in Mist.

I have not used coinbase to send Ether.  But I assume that coinbase provides some kind of a form to send Ether.  In that form, you want to specify the address you want to send Ether to.  That address should be one that you have in Mist.

**NOTE: Before you hit the send button, double and triple check the address you are sending TO.  If you send to the wrong address you've lost that money forever**

Answer (score 1):

Finally the ETH arrived within my ethereum wallet. I've used [ShapeShift.io](https://shapeshift.io) for transferring my Bitcoin into ETH. You can choose between quick or precise transaction. The diffs are explained in detail [here](https://info.shapeshift.io/blog/2016/03/11/pro-tip-difference-between-quick-and-precise-transaction). After given your ethereum wallet contract address, shapeshift generates a new bitcoin address, to which you have to send (deposit) your choosen amount of bitcoins to. Pay attention on the minimum and maximum deposit amounts (in BTC). As bitcoin refund address I've entered my coinbase BTC Wallet bitcoin address. 
After double checking all input values, I click'n'pray. ShapeShift shows you a nice info page which has it's own unique URL and is bookmarkable. After some hours, this info page notes SUCCESS. I start my ethereum wallet ... voila, the ETH are IN DA HOUSE.